# MAMP 403 Forbidden Access - Hosts - Windows 10

Tags: windows, apache, mamp, windows-10, mamp-pro

I've just been getting started to MAMP because of the easy to use interface and so forth. But when adding another host, using a different document root, I get 403 Forbidden saying that I lack permission

Maybe I'm missing something obvious? (The folder is not write-protected at least.) How would I go about fixing this?

It seems that there's some issue with the .htaccess file, I've tried to OverRide All on default but with no result yet.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Checking FollowSymLinks and Multiviews fixed this.